# Going for PhD or MS in research right after under graduation?

Tags: phd, graduate-school, masters, computer-science

I have a bachelors degree in computer science and am going for PhD or research MS, but I do not have research experience.  Can I expect to successfully obtain a PhD?  What are the major problems faced by a student who has no prior research experience but has good technical knowledge in computer science (but perhaps less so in mathematics)?

Comment: I think removing the "in India" part might make this sufficiently general to be of value to all.

Comment: If you don't have any research experience, how do you know you want to become a researcher?

Comment: @Paul Hiemstra Inspiration from lot of other people and Interest towards research are the two factors that motivated me.

Answer (score 4):

In certain disciplines it's very common to enter a Ph.D/MS+thesis program straight out of an undergraduate degree. Computer science is one such discipline. Usually you spend the first year or two in the Ph.D program getting up to speed and doing research. For an MS+Thesis program, things are more compressed, but you also aren't expected to produce research of the same **scope**.

While it's always better to have some research experience as an undergraduate (and this helps your grad application) it's not a requirement for success at the graduate level.

Comment: I want some more in depth information. General explanation is found everywhere even in university websites.

Comment: @PradeepG Suresh gives you the information that is available given the limited details you provided in your question. Bottom line, it will be a bit harder to get in, but not impossible. You'll have to work hard, but every PhD has to.

Comment: The short answer to your first question is: yes, you can expect to successfully complete a Ph.D. For the second, you'll need maybe a little "catchup time", but nothing seriously bad.